# How to find what is causing an error in error_log

Tags: php, linux, apache, shell

I'm looking for something in my system that is causing errors to my apache error_log file, but I'm unable to find what's the script or process which is causing the error.

I'm using Plesk and the error is not logged into the `error_log` of any vhosts but at `/var/log/apache/error_log.`

Is there any way to find out what script is causing the error?

The error logged is too long to paste in full, but it seems that is some php which is executing shell commands ¿?. This is part of the error logged:

```
rm: cannot remove `prototype.js': No such file or directory
sh: 27: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
rm: cannot remove `calendar-setup.js': No such file or directory
sh: 21: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
rm: cannot remove `calendar.js': No such file or directory
sh: 117: hsperfdata_tomcat7/: Permission denied
```

Any help to find the offending script? Thanks!

Comment: You should be able to find the corresponding request in some access log file. That would help a lot. You have two criteria for that: 1. the precise time stamp and 2. the fact that the request should be logged with an error code, probably 500 in the access log file.

Comment: Thanks! This was my first try in fact, but there is nothing useful. In fact there is nothing at all in the access_log. The system has only 1 vhosts and this error_log file I'm refering is the default error_log (not belonging to any vhosts). The corresponding access_log is empty :(

Comment: Hm, that appears to be some shell script, not php, by the error message. Might be some housekeeping task. Try "grepping" for terms like "prototype", "hsperfdata_tomcat7", "calendar" in your project folders then.